# rename a zip file name using rename function using perl

Tags: perl, unix

This is my sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $day = strftime "%m/%d/%Y", localtime;

my $file = "abcMONcde.zip";
my $zipfile = $file;
rename("home/abc/$file","home/abc/$file.$day") || die("Error in renaming");
```

when we run this code we got an error in rename function, what's wrong with this code.

Comment: What error did you get? `or die("Can't rename \"home/abc/$file\" to \"home/abc/$file.$day\": $!\n");`

Comment: when I run this code getting error "Error in renaming"

Comment: Yes, but what error is being returned by `rename`? I showed how to obtain it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually your `$day` prints the output `abcMONcde.zip06/09/2020:`

How could you rename the file like this. Impossible. The folder doesn't allowed forward and backslash.

You need to rename `$day=~s/\//\-/g;`

Let's try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use File::Copy;

my $day = strftime "%m/%d/%Y", localtime; $day=~s/\//\-/g;
```

Could you use `-` instead of `/` its a better solution for this as per the [`brian d foy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273757/rename-a-zip-file-name-using-rename-function-using-perl#comment110138159_62274620) comments.

```
my $day = strftime "%m-%d-%Y", localtime;


my $file = "abcMONcde.zip";
my $zipfile = $file;
```

You need to consider this one store the path in a single variable (Actual path and Destination path).

```
my $actfilename = "home/abc/$file";
my $destfilename = "home/abc/$file.$day";
```

Some times direct path doesn't work (In my experiences)

```
rename($actfilename,$destfilename) || die("Error in renaming");
```

Comment: Instead of starting with slashes is the `strftime` code then replacing them with dashes, just use dashes in the format. `"%m-%d-%Y"`

Comment: Excellent champ.. I didn't see.. Thanks for pointing out. +1

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I think the problem is happening with dir now it resolved.